# jQuery remove( ) with event passed in as a parameter

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code which detects which `<img>` tag is clicked based on the id attribute. Then if "delete" button is clicked, the selected `<img>` will be removed/deleted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
        var frame = $(this).attr("id");   //can it be done this way?
        $("button").click(function () {
        $("img").remove(frame);           //can I pass the event in as a parameter?
        $("button").unbind();
        $(this).unbind();
        }); 
    });                             
});
```

I am very new to jQuery and therefore having a hard time at the syntax. Appreciate for all the great helps.

Comment: Why are you binding event handler inside other event?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$("img").remove(frame);
```

Should be:

```
$("#"+frame).remove();
```

Provided that, you give an unique id to `img`.

**Full code & Demo**: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/Gusn7/</kbd>

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Just to be clear the "frame" itself is not a name of the id. What I want to achieve is that I want to pass that selected `<img>` tag to remove(). Can it be done?

Comment: then what? What are you storing in `frame`?

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood the jQuery concept previously. From your suggested method I think it should be working, but unfortunately it is not. I am still figuring out why.

Comment: what is the id of the image?

Comment: I realized that it has something to do with my `<img>` being a child of `<div>`. So now I resort to `$("#image").find("#"+frame).remove()`, with `#image` being the id of the div. However my images still cannot be deleted. Is it has something to do with my images being echoed by PHP? When I place a testing `<img>` outside PHP, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

**HTML**

```
<img id="someId" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
<button target-id="someId">Delete</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
        $("button").click(function () {
            var frame = $(this).attr("target-id");
            $("#" + frame).remove(); 
            $("button").unbind();
            $(this).unbind();
        });
});
```

**Demo**: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/Gusn7/1/</kbd>

`target-id` is the custom attribute.It should be the `id` of the `img`

---

If your `button` is always next to the `image` then you can use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
            $("button").click(function () {
                $(this).prev("img").remove(); 
                $(this).unbind();
            });
    });
```

**Demo**: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/Gusn7/3/</kbd>

---

Your code is wrong

```
$("img").click(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
```

Should be any one event... `img` click or `button` click

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
            $("button").click(function () {
                ("#imgIDName").remove(); 
           });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $imgs = $('img');
    $("img").click(function () {
        $imgs.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    })
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("img.selected").remove(); //can I pass the event in as a parameter?
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r4XKH/)

Comment: As I mentioned to @Amit, I realized that it has something to do with my `<img>` being a child of `<div>`. So now I resort to `$("#image").find("#"+frame).remove()`, with `#image` being the id of the div. However my images still cannot be deleted. Is it has something to do with my images being echoed by PHP? When I place a testing `<img>` outside PHP, it works.